# Python code to have information of ASIN Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-product-api

I’m trying to request some information of ASIN numbers inside Amazon. I’m trying to use similar code like this:

```
import boto3
import json

amazon = boto3.client(
    'apapi',
    aws_access_key_id='',
    aws_secret_access_key='',
    region_name='us'
)

response = amazon.lookup(
    ItemId='B07VGRJDFY',
    ResponseGroup='ItemAttributes,Images,Offers',
    #AssociateTag='YOUR_ASSOCIATE_TAG',
    Condition='All',
    IdType='ASIN'
)

data = json.loads(response['Items'][0]['Item'].to_json())

title = data['ItemAttributes']['Title']
brand = data['ItemAttributes']['Brand']
image_url = data['LargeImage']['URL']
price = data['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice']

product_data = {
    'title': title,
    'brand': brand,
    'image_url': image_url,
    'price': price
}

with open('product_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(product_data, f)
```

I don;t know how to make it work. From the resources group later I will request other elements but for now with test purposes that ones.

How can be modified the code to work?

Of course I have my secret keys created in AWS and they are active.

Thank you

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the code. Any errors?

Comment: There is no ['apapi' client in boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html), and 'us' is not a valid AWS region.  Presumably you're asking about Amazon's API, not AWS.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes I see that message error. Really what I want is to obtain the UPC of some ASIN numbers. What is the best way to do in API you say?